# grub does not update

Tags: command-line, boot, updates

I edit: `/boot/grub/menu.lst` and `/etc/default/grub`, but the terminal did not allow to update the **Grub**

the code from the terminal:

```
user@user-desktop:~$ sudo update-grub
/etc/default/grub: 29: menuentry: not found
```

Comment: You need to include the menu.lst file in your question if you expect people to help here. Probably you have made a mistake with the syntax of the file.

Comment: Anyway, the '29' in the error message is the line number where the mistake probably is.

Answer (score 1):

Check the file `/etc/default/grub`. There is something wrong on line 29. Maybe a typo or something else. Check the entry on this line against other similar entries.

Comment: i cant edit this file /etc/default/grub the edit commend is not working why??

Comment: @user143588 sudo vim /etc/default/grub

Answer (score 0):

Try to install `grub-pc` package,it will create a new `grub` file inside `/etc/default` and thereby you can easily update the grub.

```
sudo apt-get install grub-pc
```